# Disable table using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this checkbox, how to disable a table (disable all the input fields in the table) whenever I check the checkbox?

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="view" value="d">N/A</label>
```

Is it possible using purely JavaScript and not jQuery.

This is the code now

```
var elems = document.getElementById('table-id').querySelectorAll('input,select,textarea');
document.getElementById('check').onchange = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].disabled = true;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].disabled = false;
        }    
        }
    }
```

and the table

```
<table id='table-id' border="1">
```

but it shows error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

Comment: What do you mean when you say "disable a table"?

Comment: its input fields cannot be edited, written to

Comment: It is a table that has fields in it. text field, time, number, drop down and check boxes

Comment: So, you have a `table` _containing_ a number of `input` fields, and you want to disable the inputs??

Comment: @Matt 
Yes, precisely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery, it is easy:

```
$("#tableId").find(":input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Using Javascript, it is a little longer:

```
var elems = document.getElementById('tableId').querySelectorAll('input,select,textarea');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6s7QL/2/**

***Update***:

Added your checkbox code:

```
document.getElementById('checkboxId').onchange = function () {...
```

Comment: Sorry, but I just said to disable it using checkbox in javascript.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: O yes, old habit of `attr`. Corrected.

Comment: And the OP want pure JS, **not** jQuery... (?)

Comment: vaizaren and @brasofilo: Yes I saw that, was stuck up with queryselectorall while editing. Meanwhile, you guys downvoted.

Comment: Well, that's the problem of trying to be the [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) ;) Retracted and reverted

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Comment: @vaizaren: you are getting that error in the fiddle?

Comment: @vaizaren: please check the element id carefully.

Comment: @vaizaren: Where is the id on checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pure JavaScript version to do the trick you want:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableId'),
    inputs = table.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxId');

checkbox.onchange = function(e) {
    if(checkbox.checked) {
        disableTable(true);
    } else {
        disableTable(false);
    }
}

function disableTable(disableState) {
    for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = disableState;
    }
}
```

And here is the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E87xk/).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null js.html:43
(anonymous function)

Comment: The provided code in JSFiddle works fine. The error is specific to your **customized** code and the reason is that you don't have a table with `tableId`. Make sure to write the `id` of your `table` instead of `tableId` in the above code.